Convert and insert incorrect date format of example ''May 1 202'' to date format
I have a table called invoice where columns as 'invoiceno', 'invoicedate', 'invoicedate2'. Due to a mistake the invoicedate column datatype is set as nvarchar(10) and the data is passed as date therefore the data is saved in the format of below example:
"May  1 202"
the year last character is missing and I need to change the data into correct format for year 2024 and save as datetime format in column invoicedate2
Expected is May  1 202 --> 2024-05-01

So what have you tried and where did you get stuck? Seems pretty easy to add a 4 to the end (assuming all are 2024) and then convert to a datetime? (FYI datetime2 is the recommended way to store datetimes now. Combined with an update statement should be all you need?

In case you are not aware, a proper datetime/datetime2 column doesn't store the data in any kind of user format, its stored in a binary format. So specifying a new format is not relevant, because you have already specified a datetime datatype.

Fix the database type and reenter the data. There's no way to determine what year May  1 202 refers to. The truncations caused by nvarchar(10) will only get worse. June means the decade just got truncated. Come August or September you'll start losing the day as well

update invoice set canceldatetime2=cast(CONCAT(CancelDateTime,3) as datetime) used above and solved the problem thans @DaleK for heads up

you still need to convert the final column into datetime, i hope you did that at leasat

You can try something like:
UPDATE invoice
SET invoicedate2 = NULLIF(COALESCE(
    TRY_CONVERT(DATETIME, invoicedate),
    TRY_CONVERT(DATETIME, invoicedate + '4')
    ), '1900-01-01')

The above will attempt to convert the date text first without and then with a "4" appended. If unsuccessful, the result is null. Note that an empty string will convert to a 1900-01-01, so the NULLIF() function replaces that with a null.
If you know that all values follow the "mmm dd yyy" (truncated) form, you can use the following simplified version.
UPDATE invoice
SET invoicedate2 = CONVERT(DATETIME, invoicedate + '4')

Sample results:



invoicedate
invoicedate2




2024-01-31
2024-01-31 00:00:00.000


MAY  1 202
2024-05-01 00:00:00.000


          
null


junk
null


null
null



See this db<>fiddle.

CONVERT will only work by accident. We have no idea of knowing what the actual year is. From this week, the decade will disappear as well. In September, the entire day part

OP specifically requested 2024.

Based on what criteria? Just their assumptions? Besides, dates are already stored as June  1 20 by now. And for May 1 2024 to get truncated, there are multiple spaces, or the application code performs a worse trunctation

If the data is so little that 2024 can be assumed and earlier dates aren't destroyed as well, the type can be changed to datetime2 as well and the data re-entered. If the OP expects the mistake to go unnoticed in a production system though ...

@PanagiotisKanavos - The OP specifically stated in their requirements: " I need to change the data into correct format for year 2024". Also, the fact that the sample data shows an extra space before the day-of-month, suggests a fixed format with a 3-letter month abbreviation - possibly the equivalent of CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 0) = 'Jun  3 202'. The OP has been dealt a batch of corrupt data and is taking the proper steps to fix it up and assign the fixed values to a properly typed column. If both of the preceding conditions (year and date format) hold true, the above should work.

I solved the problem with below query
update invoice set invoicedate=cast(CONCAT(invoicedate2,4) as datetime) 


The column names you use are not the same as in your question! Please ensure your question and answer are consistent.

And the other answer includes this option, so you should accept that answer rather than add your own
